# Hasse diagram with maximal chain not counted in maximal anti-chain

Tags: graph-theory, order-theory

> Construct a post (Hasse diagram) that contains a maximal anti-chain of size $r$ and, after removing a chain $C$ of maximal size, it still contains an anti-chain of size $r$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this partial order; I’ll let you find the right maximal chain to remove.

```
        *     *  
         \   / \
          \ /   \
           *     *  
          / \   /  
         /   \ /  
        *     *  
         \   /  
          \ /  
           *
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I'm not sure when removing the chain, does it also remove nodes that are in other chains. The original diagram. <br>

    a*   *b
     |  /|
     | / |
    c*   *d
     |\  |
     | \ |
    e*   *f
     |  /
     | /
     *g

This diagram has maximal antichain of size 2, maximal chain has size 4
If I remove chain a,c,f,g it becomes
    e*   *b
         |
  |
  *d
And this has maximal antichain of 2. Is that correct? SOrry if I asked the obvious: I'm new to this.

Comment: I did not know how to format comment to look the same as it is written. Here is the diagram I wanted to show. Thank you for your help. [link](http://pastebin.com/gzrGUqET)  
@brian-m-scott

Comment: @HaiPhan: Removing $\{a,c,f,g\}$ works, but what’s left is a little different from what you have: you should have $e\le b$, $d\le b$, and $\{e,d\}$ an antichain. Remember, $e\le b$ in the original partial order, and removing $c$ doesn’t change that.